# Passing a JSON object into Jquery function for use in a modal window

Tags: jquery, json, modal-dialog

I have a JSON object created in a PHP function:

```
function get_jason($id) {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_SERVER.'; dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"'); 
        $sql = "SELECT name, pos
                FROM parks
                WHERE id = '$id'
                ORDER BY id desc"
                ;
        $result = $pdo->query($sql);

        $data_array = $result->fetchAll();

        foreach($data_array as $stuff) {

        $name = $data_array['name'];
        $pos = $data_array['pos'];

            $stuff[] = array('name' => $name, 'pos' => $pos);
        }

            $data = json_encode($stuff);

        return $data;}
```

That works, and outputs as follows:
{"name":"Bloody Skillet","0":"Bloody Skillet","pos":"41.12393,-77.779448","1":"41.12393,-77.779448","2":{"name":null,"pos":null}}

Then I take $data and put it into the following code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="<?php echo $data ?>">Open modal for <?php echo $id ?></button>
```

This is then referenced by a script in jQuery:

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') 

  var modal = $(this)

alert(recipient.name)
```

No matter what I do, I can't seem to be able to reference recipient.name or recipient.pos. I have tried using JSON decode, JSON parse, tried accessing recipient directly.

Comment: erkaner: I'm not sure what you're asking?

Comment: here: `'show.bs.modal'` what is `show`, an id?

Comment: sorry. That shows the modal window. I can post the modal window code if you like, but that has been working for some time. It's the $data which then is received as recipient that I'm having trouble with. I'm pretty strong in PHP but a total JavaScript novice. I've read about a hundred articles, tutorials, and manuals trying to figure out how to access the array once it is brought over to Javascript, but all of the things that look like they should work don't. I'm missing something simple, I suspect.

Comment: I know nothing about PHP but some about jquery and js. In such statements you generally either have `'.className'` or `'#id'` but in your case it is neither of them. Maybe, it is just beyond my knowledge, but just wanted to share.